# undefined reference error in VScode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, undefined-reference

I'm testing the how to use extern in C ,so I create three files for main.c, test.c, headfile.h . I want to declare variable and function in headfile.h,define in the test.c ,then print out the variable and call function at the main.c
It works successfully by using Dev c++,however, when I put the exact same files into VScode it show errors that there are undefined reference to variables

the error messages
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMydK.png)

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"D:\My Documents\Desktop\CODE\c\VScode\externTest\headfile.h"
int gVar = 1;

int main(void)
{
    extern float a;

    printf("a = %f\n",a);
    printf("gVar = %d\n",gVar);
    printf("aa = %d\n",aa);
    printf("bb = %f\n",bb);
    function ();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

### test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "D:\My Documents\Desktop\CODE\c\VScode\externTest\headfile.h" 
float a = 100;
int aa = 200;
float bb = 300;

void function (void){
    printf("yeh you got it!!\n");
    extern int gVar;
    gVar++;
    printf("gVar in test.c function = %d",gVar);
}
```

### headfile.h

```
extern int aa;
extern float bb;
void function(void);
```

Comment: Could you provide your compilation line ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like your `main.c` file is not being linked with `test.c`.
I have been able to reproduce the exact same error message using the following compilation commands:

```
$ gcc main.c
/tmp/ccVqEXL5.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `a'
main.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `aa'
main.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `bb'
main.c:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `function'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To fix this, simply add your `test.c` file to the compilation by doing `gcc main.c test.c`.

Answer (score 7):

The answer provided by @Ra'Jiska is correct but doing it is not straightforward if you want to compile your code using VScode. You need to indicate to `tasks.json` (file generated by VScode with the commands to compile the code) which extra files your program needs to compile.

More specifically, you need to add the line `"${fileDirname}/test.c"` in the "args" section of the "tasks" list.

Comment: what if the file I need is a library with a .h and a .lib. What and where do I have to add to .json?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to include extra class files and this is your original run command:

`cd "c:\myfolder\" ; if ($?) { g++ mainfile.cpp -o mainfile } ; if ($?) { .\mainfile}`

add the extra file names (Shape.cpp & Circle.cpp for example) like this:

`cd "c:\myfolder\" ; if ($?) { g++ mainfile.cpp Shape.cpp Circle.cpp -o mainfile } ; if ($?) { .\mainfile}`

and run again