# mxchip press button send signal to Azure IoT

Tags: c, azure-iot-hub

Can someone share an example or provide some guidance how I can add that when a button in the mxchip IoT device is pressed the signal is sent to Azure IoT? I am using Azure's [example code](https://github.com/azure-rtos/getting-started/tree/master/MXChip/AZ3166/app)

I see the function in board_init.c that lights up the light:

```
weak void button_a_callback()
{

WIFI_LED_ON();
AZURE_LED_ON();
USER_LED_ON();
if (BUTTON_A_IS_PRESSED)
{
    val += 32;
    if (val > 2047)
        val = 2047;
    RGB_LED_SET_R(val);
    RGB_LED_SET_G(val);
    RGB_LED_SET_B(val);
}
//set_led_state(true); I'd like to add something like this
```

}

and in nx_client.c to set the led state (true or false) when the command is received from Azure IoT:

```
static void set_led_state(bool level)
{
if (level)
{
    printf("\tLED is turned ON\r\n");
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
else
{
    printf("\tLED is turned OFF\r\n");
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}
}
```

How can I link these two functions, meaning from button_a_callback to call nx_client.c set_led_state function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the functions of nx_clinet.c in board_inti.c program by including the nx_client.h header file in board_inti.h file. To do this add the following line in the board_inti.h file

```
#include "nx_client.h"
```

You would have to remove the key work static before the function set_led_state as it restricts the function from being accessed externally

To avoid implicit declaration warning, declare the start_led_state function in nx_client.h before endif

```
void set_led_state(bool level)
```

Now you can call the set_led_state function from either button_a_callback or HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback code block

You may want to refer the following links for any issues
[How to split a C program into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128664/how-to-split-a-c-program-into-multiple-files)
[undefined reference error in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117196/undefined-reference-error-in-vscode)
[How to call the static function from another c file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425790/how-to-call-the-static-function-from-another-c-file)